# How to debug tabindex

Tags: html, debugging, tabindex

Are there any tools or plugins for web browser to debug `tabindex` functionality? It seems that `tabindex` attributes are correct but it behaves not as expected. Or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use FireFox, get the [Webdeveloper toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/). You can display the tab index, this may help you debug.

And here's where to find that option:

[image]

Answer (score 36):

You can use the developer tools in Chrome, Firefox, and IE by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and navigating to the console tab and then insert the following:

`document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {console.log(document.activeElement)})`

Now when you tab through the focusable items the `activeElement` including its `tabindex`, if you have one set, will be printed to the console.

Answer (score 4):

In Chrome you can right-click an element and select "Inspect" from the context menu. Then switch to the Console and type `$0.tabIndex`.

Explanation: $0 - $4 refer to the last 4 elements you have inspected. `tabIndex` is a standard property of the DOM API's `HTMLEelement`.

See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference